# How to change background of tab indicator image?

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android-tabhost, android-button, android-icons

[image: StyleMe's image is style_link]

Here is an image.
i want tabview image background like this.When it is not selected it shows white image and when it is selected it shows green image.

Here is the code:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
TabHost tabhost = getTabHost();
Intent one = new Intent().setClass(this, StyleMe.class);
TabSpec tb1=tabhost.newTabSpec("One").setIndicator("",resources.getDrawable
(R.drawable.style_link)).setContent(one); 
tabhost.addTab(tb1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better solution is to use background with selector, so you don't have to check onTabChanged and do manual update.:

```
private void initTabsAppearance(TabWidget tabWidget) {
    // Change background
    for(int i=0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++)
        tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg);
}
```

Where tab_bg is an xml drawable with selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_normal" />
</selector>
```

Hope this will help.